# Need advice/help with website structure with caching, don't want to set 777 to doc root

Tags: php, linux, web-applications, codeigniter, web

I have a web application, based on CodeIgniter framework, which simply fetches data from stock exchange feeds and displays it. To enable caching the plan is to create a static HTML file once the stock exchange is closed coz there will not be any change in the stocks. Here is the structure for doc root of website

```
/index.php the CI controller
/application
/system
```

The URLs are

```
mysite.com/marketwatch.html - served by index method of marketwatch controller
mysite.com/marketwatch/marketindex/some-index-name.html  - served by marketindex method of marketwatch controller and takes some-index-name as argument
mysite.com/marketwatch/scripdetails/some-scrip-name.html  - served by scripdetails method of marketwatch controller and takes some-scrip-name as argument
```

Now what I can do is to create a path like `DOCROOT/marketwatch/marketindex` and `DOCROOT/marketwatch/scripdetails/` and set 777 perms on these two so that at right time of the day the files are created in these two folders and .htaccess will direct Apache to serve these files instead of invoking whole CI framework and save sever of some botheration. The problem is

- setting 777 for a folder that is served by webserver sounds wrong
- I can't set 777 perms for doc root to create marketwatch.html

Can some one guide me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you create the "cached" files in advance (even if they are empty) and give them 0666 permissions, PHP will be allowed to modify these files to update them (but don't never delete them, or they'll lose those permissions and they won't be the same the next time you create them).

Comment: but those files will be served by apache instead of the framework?

Comment: I don't know how CodeIgniter works, but if you put the files inside the code igniter file strucure, probably the framework will try to load them. If you place them outside code igniter, then sure they'll be server by apache only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set 0777 permissions with chmod function from php.